# PHP option POST is empty

Tags: php, forms, post, html-select

I have these two input types:

The first one:

```
echo "<input type='radio' name='tipo_campo' value='$enum_array[$i]' required>" . '  ' .$enum_array[$i] . '<br>';
```

if I do:

```
echo $_POST['tipo_campo'];
```

It will display the correct value.

But for this:

```
echo "<option name='tipo_unid' value='$tipo_unidade[0]'>". $tipo_unidade[1] ."</option>";
```

the

```
echo $_POST['tipo_unid'];
```

Will be empty.

I have tested the $tipo_unidade[0] separately, and it has the correct value, so I know that's not the problem.

Why does the first POST display the correct value, and the second one is empty?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: `<option ...>` tags go inside `<select ...>` tags where the `select` will have the `name` attribute that you'll use with `$_POST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For option we should not use name there we are only supposed to give value name has to give in the select tag

For example

```
<select name="xxx">
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
<option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

Sure this will helps you

Answer (score 1):

usage:

```
<select name="option">
   <option value="1" selected>First</option>
   <option value="2">Second</option>
</select>
```

post/get

```
echo $_POST['option'];
```

output:

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this

<select name="tipo_unid">
   <option value=<?=$tipo_unidade[0];?>><?=$tipo_unidade[1];?></option>
</select>

print_r($_POST); or echo $_POST['tipo_unid'];
```